# Drupal 7 and Views, contextual filters searching through multiple/combined fields. Is it possible?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, filtering, drupal-views

I've worked with Drupal 7 and Views for a while now and I'm familiar with what Views allow by default and what is available as modular add-ons. Today I've come across an issue with Contextual filters, which allow you to pass in an argument via the URL and use this to filter the returned data.

Normal filters on the other hand can be exposed as a form and also allow for a field combination module which means we can search field{1,2,3} all at once and display the data depending on this input. (views_combined_fields)

Is it possible to tell Views to show me all rows (WHERE field1="test" OR WHERE field2="test" OR WHERE field3="test") but by default, if I add in multiple contextual filters only one of them is being triggered. In this example the "test" value is obtained from the url /data/test.

My problem is that users have a default group, but they also have the option to be added into other groups which are set in the field{1,2,3} fields. My current view shows all users WHERE group = "test" but I want users who have a secondary or tertiary group of "test" to also be displayed in this list.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, you are talking about Views Arguments, watch the [tutorial video](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode39) from
MustardSeedMedia.com. And useful video about [Views 3 User Interface](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode47)